# How to convert some queries from sql to sparql?

Tags: sql, sparql

I am just learning Sparql and I have the following tables:

Countries, European Country, City and Capital

I would like to know how to make the following queries, because I didnt understand them...

1) Which country has the city "Paris" as capital.
2) Print all the European Countries
3) Print all the countries and theis capitals.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: In RDF, you don't have tables! An RDF dataset consist of a set of triples. Please read an RDF tutorial and a SPARQL tutorial. And then you can think about a schema of your RDF dataset and then, finally, you can make a SPARQL query based on your schema.

Comment: If you are coming from the SQl world, a probably good way to understand RDF, apart from the advice by @AKSW, is too look at [R2RML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/r2rml/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This said, there is DBpedia that offers info similar to what is described, and is a good playground. To query it, http://yasgui.org (which is a better sparql editor) or http://factforge.net/sparql (which is our own integration, a few months old, but has some extra goodies).

**Which country has the city "Paris" as capital**

```
select * {
  ?x a dbo:Country; dbo:capital dbr:Paris
}
```

The [yasgui](http://yasgui.org/short/HJpOAGW3e) results will surprise you:

```
dbr:Bourbon_Restoration
dbr:France
dbr:Francia
dbr:French_Fifth_Republic
dbr:Kingdom_of_France
dbr:Office_International_d'Hygiène_Publique
dbr:Second_French_Empire
dbr:West_Francia
```

I understand all the historic kingdoms, but     dbr:Office_International_d'Hygiène_Publique is a bit of a shock. The reason is that it's an International Organization ([uses `Infobox Former International Organization`](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Office_International_d'Hygi%C3%A8ne_Publique&action=edit), and it [redirects to](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_Former_International_Organization&redirect=no) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_former_country, which "is currently being merged with Template:Infobox country". See http://mappings.dbpedia.org/index.php/Cleaning_up_Countries

[factforge](http://factforge.net/sparql?name=&infer=true&sameAs=false&query=PREFIX+dbo%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fontology%2F%3E%0APREFIX+dbr%3A+%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org%2Fresource%2F%3E%0Aselect+*+%7B%0A++%3Fx+a+dbo%3ACountry%3B+dbo%3Acapital+dbr%3AParis%0A%7D&execute=) returns even more results from linked datasets (all these mean just France):

```
geodata:3017382/
http://ontologi.es/place/FR
http://psi.oasis-open.org/iso/3166/#250
leaks:country-FRA
wfr:fr
```

**All the European Countries**

That's better because there happens to be a Wikipedia category:

```
select * {
  ?x a dbo:Country; dct:subject dbc:Countries_in_Europe
}
```

[yasgui](http://yasgui.org/short/S1x_OXWng)

**all countries and their capitals**

```
select * {
  ?x a dbo:Country; dbo:capital ?capital
}
```

This returns a bunch of historic countries and capitals, and again some international organizations, eg

```
League_of_Nations
International_Authority_for_the_Ruhr
Japanese_occupation_of_British_Borneo
```

SO THEN, you may have better luck with Wikidata (https://query.wikidata.org/). At https://twitter.com/search?q=wikidatafacts%20country you can find a bunch of interesting queries related to countries.

**countries and capitals on Wikidata**

```
select ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel {
  ?country wdt:P36 ?city
  filter exists {?country wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6256}
    SERVICE wikibase:label {
        bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,pl,ru,es" .
    }
} order by ?countryLabel
```

It uses a bunch of `Qnn` and `Pnn` but you can decode them when you mouse-over.

- How did I find that `wdt:P36` means "capital"? [Search for property:capital](https://www.wikidata.org/w/index.php?search=&search=property%3Acapital&title=Special:Search&go=Go)
- why `filter exists`? Because a country may have several subtypes of `wd:Q6256` "country", and if I use that in the main query, it returns several results per country. This way it returns only one.

**Map**

You can also easily [display it on a map](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23defaultView%3AMap%0Aselect%20%3Fcountry%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3Fcoords%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP36%20%3Fcity%0A%20%20filter%20exists%20%7B%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ6256%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fcoords%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7Bbd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%2Cpl%2Cru%2Ces%22%7D%0A%7D%20):

```
#defaultView:Map
select ?country ?countryLabel ?city ?cityLabel ?coords {
  ?country wdt:P36 ?city
  filter exists {?country wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q6256}
  ?city wdt:P625 ?coords
  SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en,pl,ru,es"}
}
```

See a couple of shots https://twitter.com/valexiev1/status/844870994942603264